# How can I remove accounts from Outlook 2007 without deleting emails?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, imap, pop3, google-workspace

I have been using a POP email account from bluehost.com and I just switched to Google Apps. The email address is staying the same. I tried to go in and edit the server settings but the account type it set to POP and it is grayed out so I can not change it to IMAP.

What I ended up doing was creating a second account with the same e-mail address but with the google apps (gmail) server information. That account is now listed much farther below my normal "Inbox" in the folders list.

I also have a second personal Gmail account that I have in my accounts list.

How can I get the all the e-mails to just show up in my normal "Inbox" ?

How can I delete the old POP account from the account list wit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's a lot of synchronization that needs to occur for IMAP accounts you can't change the PST file that Outlook IMAP messages are received in. You can, however, add a rule that moves/copies all messages received from your IMAP account into you old PST file.

Alternatively, you can just drag the new account folder (in the Navigation Pane) up to the top of the list and leave the old PST for reference. You could also copy the old emails into the new IMAP PST but that would then sync those old emails to your GMail account, which maybe is not what you want (and may take a long time).

Comment: +1 - That's great. It tells me almost everything I need to know. Just one more thing - how can I remove the account from the account list without removing all the messages in the inbox?

Comment: When you delete the Account, using the Account Settings dialog, it should keep the Data File in the list. Just to make sure you might want to make a copy of the PST file just in case. If for some reason it is removed from the Navigation Pane just add it back using the "File->Open->Open Outlook Data File" option.